# Select a row element based on another row element in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, ui-automation

I want to select a checkbox based on another element in the row in Selenium. Eg: How do I select the checkbox corresponding to Cricket?

```
<body>
    <table id="MyTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </td>
                <td>Football</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </td>
                <td>Cricket</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='MyTable']//tr[contains(., 'Cricket')]//input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

See check boxes in general are `input` tag, you if you want to select that using `Cricket` keyword, you can use the below **xpath** :

```
//td[text()='Cricket']/preceding-sibling::td/input
```

and in **code** :-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Cricket']/preceding-sibling::td/input")).click();
```

or

you could try with Explicit waits as well :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[text()='Cricket']/preceding-sibling::td/input"))).click();
```